# Wireless Power Transfer at 6.78 MHz Using Magnetic Resonance

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

In our situation we are using the [GaN 300W kit](https://gansystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/GSWP300W-EVBPA-User-Guide-Rev-180614.pdf) which drives a coil with 100V @ 6.78MHz. We have two coils, each with an Req = 0.5 ohm and L1 = 480uH and L2 = 432uH. The user guide mentions impedance matching networks in the block level design on page 4.

I reviewed impedance matching on [AllAbout Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/selected-topics/understanding-matching-networks/) which led me to their [L-Matching Network Calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/l-match-impedance-matching-circuits/).

I've been simulating using LTSpice and doing an AC Sweep to plot power vs frequency, expecting a properly tuned circuit to have the best response at 6.78MHz.

Simulating with a 50 Ohm load I get this:
[image: WPT No Tuning]
Expected...

I tried a tank circuit which at first did not make much sense to me since to my understanding a properly tuned tank circuit would not draw any power from an AC source that drives at the tank circuit's resonant frequency. But after reading the first response on [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373868/why-is-wireless-power-transfer-done-between-two-coils-at-their-self-resonant-fre) it actually makes sense as why this *might* work.
[image]
Same results. No improvement.

I did some variations of the L-Matching networks but had no luck... so I asked one of our engineers and he said that currently I am treating this problem as a transmission line problem (hence the L-Matching Networks) but I should actually be treating this as a lumped circuit problem, where in the simplest term I just want to make it so that the supply only sees a purely resistive load.

My first thought was putting a cap and inductor in series so that their reactive parts cancel out (im thinking a cap and inductor where in their complex number form their imaginary parts are equal but opposite) so I tried this:
[image: WPT - Series Cap]
Again, not what im looking for. Havent really looked into why this is the response but that's for another time I guess.

Looking on Stack Exchange I found the second answer to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373868/why-is-wireless-power-transfer-done-between-two-coils-at-their-self-resonant-fre) (same post as before) and he shows the equivalent circuit of a transformer which looks like the lumped circuit idea I was told to look into.

**How does a transformer turn into this lumped circuit?** It looks like the two coils are consolidated into one but how exactly is that done? And how do you tune this circuit to resonate at a desired frequency?

And sorry about this one being a little out of place but while writing this I had a thought and tried this:
[image: L-Matching Network Works?]
Unfortunately I dont have screenshots so I cant be sure but I think before I was putting L4 *before* C2 and that was giving me a circuit with an improper response to the AC Sweep. I used the L-Matching network calculator for 6.78MHz but this circuit looks a MHz off so still would need to be tuned, but is this actually a valid way to implement wireless power transfer for magnetic resonance?

When using the calculator I do two separate calculations, the first L matching network is calculated using the AC source as the source (0 reactance) and the TX coil as the load (0.5 ohm resistance). The second matching network is calculated using the RX coil as the source (0.5 ohm resistance) and 50 ohm resistor as the load (0 reactance).

If neither this nor the lumped circuit equivalent are the routes to go, how is magnetic resonance wireless power transfer implemented?

Comment: Parallel resonate both the primary and secondary inductors.

Comment: You probably have a rather LOW output resistance from the Transmitter side; use a Series LC there. And on  the Receiver side, I'd use a Parallel resonant circuit, so you build up a large voltage you can rectify. But what do I know?

Comment: I don't like your term *magnetic resonance*. It isn't magnetic resonance it's LC resonance. When you magnetically couple two independently tuned LC circuits they naturally detune each other and you need to be careful in the design (if that helps at all).

Comment: You have modelled your WPT coils as a perfect transformer with unity coupling coefficient i.e. "K L1L2 1". WPT coils are loosely coupled and typically coupling coefficient is very much lower than unity - In most cases, it is less than 0.1.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon As in a tank circuit? I guess I screwed up posting that image but I edited my post to fix it. If you look at the second photo that's now on the post I believe I did what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Pojj When looking up how to model transformers in LTSpice it gave the suggestion to start at unity but yeah I totally agree that the coupling coefficient will be much lower. Would have the coupling coefficient at unity affect my simulation in a significant way though? I guess what Im saying is, wouldnt the _response_ of the system be the same regardless of the coupling coefficient, or no?

Comment: @Andyaka so do you think that the term is misleading? The reason why I use the term is because it's in the user guide of the GaN WPT Kit we're using. Is the principle that this kit uses any different from say what WiTricity uses? (besides maybe being a simplified version of it). Particularly this: [Resonant inductive coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant_inductive_coupling)

Comment: [magnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) is not what you are wanting to do. You are wanting to resonate an LC tuned circuit and magnetically couple the field to another coil. That isn't magnetic resonance. The resonance you want is associated to inductor-capacitor resonance.

Comment: Terminology is catchy here. || In the case of a long transmit loop (in my example 100 metres of TPS mains cabling!) th transmit loop was series resonated to provide best loading of the transmit oscillator. The receive coils were parallel resonated inductors - in my case wound on ferrite U cores.

Comment: I note the claim in the linked article "In this regard, MIT researchers believe they discovered a new way to wirelessly transfer power using non-radiative electromagnetic energy resonant tunneling."  -> Maybe. I'm not sure that their coupled primary tx coil is substantively different than my direct driven loop - but maybe it is. My playing was in 1999.

Comment: Coupling matters! Try changing it to 0.1. Before using any matching circuit, use the equivalent circuit method to calculate input impedance (this is a function of coupling). Then decide how to match the impedance (this also depends on what do you want to match - Source or, Load side?)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry to take so long. I really appreciate your comments. I think this is starting to make sense. So a series LC on the TX coil and a parallel LC on the RX. If you dont mind me voicing how this is in my head.. on TX the series LC makes a low(est) possible impedance path at the tuned frequency. The source sees a purely resistive load... on RX the parallel LC sets the coil to resonate at a particular frequency. Hit it with that frequency and it'll produce a signal "stronger" than the original. Is this correct?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I took the advice to drop the coupling to 0.1 and I think it made for much more accurate simulation. So thank you Pojj! When simulating the series LC on TX and parallel LC on RX, I do get a funky output. I'll post it to the end of my original post. Are the caps right? I just used a tank circuit and series LC calculator to get it @ 6.7MHz. Wasnt sure if that was the right route though.

Comment: @Pojj I took your advice. If you'd like to see the previous comment. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: @MichaelSpalluzzi You MUST have receive resonance. About right is no good if it's not very close. Try using a C that seems slightly too low and add say 10% steps. As you approach resonance the performance will increase greatly and then drop off as you pass it.

Comment: As the first step, try using only series capacitors with both Tx and Rx coils and tuned to resonance. In the next step, depending on your coil realization, you may need to add some parallel capacitors to represent coil parasitics and adjust the series capacitors to keep the resonance.  What is your final goal - are you after high-efficiency, high power, or anything else?